# For Drupal theming do you ever have to choose between a preprocess and theme function?

Tags: drupal

I know that the difference between a theme and preprocess function is that the preprocess is called earlier and so is not limited to a single theme. Is it always the case that you could only use one or the other to achieve a theming task? Or do you sometimes have a choice of either?

Assuming you had a choice of using either, if the site only has 1 theme what is the benefits of either option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocess functions are meant for setting up variables that will be sent to the theme function or theme file.
They are for different purposes so you should not be choosing between them.
Basically...
Preprocess function contain PHP, adding variables to the variables array.
Theme functions/files output HTML depending on the variables passed to it from the preprocess function.

Answer (score 1):

Theme functions and preprocessors are different animals, and they each serve different purposes.  Whether or not to use either or both of these components depends on what you're trying to accomplish, and they are not mutually exclusive.  More info on how Drupal's presentation layer works can be found at https://www.drupal.org/node/933976 and http://themery.com/dgd7.

As you mentioned, preprocessors do run first.  They are used to manipulate certain render arrays and set up all the variables that are to be passed on to the template or theme function.  Some preprocessors might focus on menu links, others might focus on blocks, and yet others might focus on views.  You could, for example, use a `theme_preprocess_menu_link()` function to remove a `title` element from a menu link if you did not want it to appear in the final output.

Theme functions are used to process a render array into HTML code.  They serve the same purpose as template files, except that they do all their work in PHP code rather than reading in a `.tpl.php` file and merging it with the render array to produce HTML.  Theme hooks and suggestions are used to tell Drupal how it is to override its default theme to render something, using either template files or theme functions.

This design lets Drupal assign as much of the processing and logic as possible to the preprocessors and theme hooks, so that the theme functions or templates can focus on producing nice, clean markup without having to contain too much code and logic.  It also enables the output of properly-designed Drupal modules to be theme-agnostic, where the final look of that output can be adapted for any theme design.

Even if a site only has one theme, preprocessors, theme functions, theme hooks and templates are still quite useful as well as necessary for many purposes.